# Is SQLite faster because it is serverless?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

When using server-based database engines, some time will be consumed for communication. Since SQLite is serverless, does it make it faster than server-based database engines?

Comment: This question is a good candidate for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think this issue has with "Serverless" to do, notice that the SQLite has much more limitations than other known systems (Stored Procs, write to views ... Read [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.91.1.7/1/)).
Besides The application program uses SQLite's functionality through simple function calls, which reduce latency in database access – function calls within a single process are more efficient than inter-process communication.

Check this [Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

Comment: +1 for the intraprocess and interprocess communications. But though [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) (nitpick: not SQLLite) does have its limitations, indexes and writeable views are not amongst them: those are supported. What it doesn’t have is stored procedures. Other omissions: http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html.

Comment: @Martijn: Thanx for correction. So you mean supporting writing to views through INSTEAD OF triggers that provide this? By the way the +1 stil not there :)

Comment: That’s it — I’ll grant you that it has no support out-of-the-box for writable views.  And I’ve added the +1.  :-)